# Foreach( $array as $key => $value ) существование значения $value

Tags: php, foreach

Как я понимаю, цикл foreach оперирует не исходным массивом, а его копией, поэтому в примере ниже в $value будет находиться копия элементов массива.

Так почему же после прохода массива эта переменная существует и имеет значение?

```
$array = array("PHP","foo","Random Stuff","JS" );

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}

if(isset($value) && !empty($value)){
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` не копирует массив, а создает копию элемента массива в переменную. Разумеется, переменная `$value` существует после окончания цикла. А в приведенном коде, еще и `$key`. Куда им деться-то? Или Вы где-то видели, как `for` сам "убивает" за собой "счетчик"?

Всё прекрасно описано в документации. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Спасибо! Как я понял, чтобы уйти от этой проблемы, нужно изменить область видимости, например, загнав все в функцию, тогда после выполнения `function f($array){foreach( $array as $key => $value ){}} f($array);` мы потеряем связь с этими переменными.

Answer (score 1):

Чистка мусора. Чтобы ваше приложение не отжирало 100% оперативной памяти.

Comment: Не понял про чистку мусора, ведь в переменной есть значение, которое равно `JS`. Т.е. получается, что при любом `foreach` нужно постоянно удалять переменную, чтобы не наткнуться на неё далее по коду?

Comment: @kosinus777 да, с этим еще связан знатный антипаттерн при передаче данных в foreach по ссылке. При использовании ООП-подхода границы определения переменной совпадают с областью видимости метода, и при следовании обычным конвенциям проблема отпадает.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли разобраться!